# Why do later versions of Node take so long to install?

Tags: c++, linux, node.js, raspberry-pi2, nvm

I am using nvm on Raspbian on my Raspberry Pi.

When I `nvm install v0.10.26` it happens in a few minutes.

When I `nvm install v0.12.6` it has to g++ and cc a bunch of stuff and it takes forever. Why the difference? It looks like it's working hard on building OpenSSL, V8, and crypto. Is there something new or different in later versions of Node.js?